# Executing a Process on Windows using Remote SSH Connection

Tags: c#, windows

Hi i am trying to execute a process on a remote windows machine using SSH. I used Renci.SshNet to connect to the remote windows 10 machine, uploaded an executable (whcih works Fine i.e open in fore ground when executed by a user on the machine) however, when i try to execute it over SSH connection it runs in background with no intilization. I dont know about this strange behavior. This is the sample code which i used to run the remote executeable.

```
    public void SshCommandExecutor(string MachineIP, string MachineUserID, string MachineUserPassword, string command)
    {
        SshClient cSSH = new SshClient(MachineIP, 22, MachineUserID, MachineUserPassword);
        cSSH.Connect();
        SshCommand x = cSSH.RunCommand(command);
        cSSH.Disconnect();
        cSSH.Dispose();
        log(x.Result.ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

So what i did was i uplaoded the executable file using ssh then i initiated a vnc session on the remote machine and using vncdotool* exeuted the remote process via command line

*https://pypi.org/project/vncdotool/